# Can I use Pyspark RDD as Pandas DataFrame? Limitations of Pyspark/spark over Pandas in data analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, bigdata

Pandas data-frame is very useful to perform data analysis but it can't handle big data very well. Therefore I am thinking of using PySpark when-ever there is Big Data. So my questions are:

1.**How to convert Pandas DataFrame into Pyspark RDD and back to pandas data-frame?**

```
dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':[pd.to_datetime('2018-7-7 00:10:00 UTC'),pd.to_datetime('2018-7-8 00:10:00 UTC')],'UserId':[111,222], 'Name' ['a', 'b']})
```

2.**What are the possible limitations Pyspark/spark is having over the Pandas to perform data analysis?**

Also please suggest useful references, books, videos that I can use in this case?

Comment: Can you please paste your code as `code`, not as a screenshot?

Comment: removed screenshot  :)

Comment: For your first answer, I would suggest you to see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error Will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest any reliable link for the Q 2. Since I am using pandas for data analysis as of now and familiar with some spark concepts but I don't know yet whether I will be able to perform all those operations using spark which I am able to do using pandas.

Comment: I use both pyspark and pandas, sometimes even simultaneously, that of course depends on your need, if you want to process your data in distributed artitechture, then pysaprk is your go. Probably it may not be as easy as using Pandas because the resources of Pyspark are reletively smaller than the pandas. You may have to make  `User defined functions` to get your things done, as not all functionality of Pandas may be available. A quick googling gave me this: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-Pandas-DataFrames-over-Spark-SQL-data-frames

Answer (score -1):

> Pandas -> pyspark

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`
```

> Pyspark -> pandas

```
pdf = sparkDf.toPandas()
```

Comment: Can you explain it in detail, please? means I want to know whether there are any steps before: sparkDf = context.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am getting this error Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number after execution of spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`