# pyspark pandas object as dataframe - TypeError

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, elmo

**Edit**: **RESOLVED**
I think the problem is with the multi-dimensional arrays generated from Elmo inference. I averaged all the vectors and then used the final average vector for all words in the sentence as output and it works now for converting to a data frame. Now, I have to make it faster, will check back on using threads.

Trying to use ElmoForManyLangs pre-trained model from following github to generate Elmo embeddings for sentences in a pyspark data frame. However, I am not able to convert the resulting object to a dataframe.

https://github.com/HIT-SCIR/ELMoForManyLangs

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim

sys.path.append('/tmp/python-elmo/elmoManyLangs/elmoManyLangsGit/ELMoForManyLangs-master')
from elmoformanylangs import Embedder
e = Embedder('/mnt/tmp/python-elmo/elmoManyLangs/english/')

new_list = []

input = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/input/file")

words = input.withColumn("wordlist", split(trim(input["description"]), " ")).dropna().select("product_name","wordlist").limit(1)

wordsPd=words.toPandas()

for t in wordsPd.itertuples():
        new_list.append(np.average(np.array([np.average(x,axis=0) for x in e.sents2elmo(t[2])]), axis=0).tolist())

wordsPd = wordsPd.assign(embeddings=new_list)
myDf = spark.createDataFrame(wordsPd)
myDf.registerTempTable("myDf")


wordsPd
```

0  my_product_name  ...  0     [[0.1606223, 0.09298285, -0.3494971, 0.2...
[1 rows x 3 columns]

```
wordsPd.dtypes

product_name    object 
description      object 
embeddings    object 
dtype: object
```

Here is the error for creating the dataframe.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1068, in _infer_type
    return _infer_schema(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1094, in _infer_schema
    raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'object'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1068, in _infer_type
    return _infer_schema(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1096, in _infer_schema
    fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1096, in <listcomp>
    fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'object'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1068, in _infer_type
    return _infer_schema(obj)
.........
.........
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7355529425587840217.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
...........
...........  
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7355529425587840217.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
.........
.........
    raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'object'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1068, in _infer_type
    return _infer_schema(obj)
.........
.........
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'object'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1068, in _infer_type
    return _infer_schema(obj)
........
........
........
........
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7355529425587840217.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 691, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
........
........
........
........
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Pandas dataframe into Spark dataframe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to aggregate vectors using following which made the multi dimensional arrays into one list.

```
for t in wordsPd.itertuples():
        new_list.append(np.average(np.array([np.average(x,axis=0) for x in e.sents2elmo(t[2])]), axis=0).tolist())
```