# Load pickles (pandas dataframes) in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a lot of small pickle files that contain `pd.Dataframe()` objects. I need to load these in a pyspark dataframe. Firstly, I cannot seem to find a way to load directly pickle files from adls/dbfs into a pyspark dataframe, using `df = spark.read.format`. Because I couldn't find such a way, I decided to load the files using `pickle.load` from by dbfs directory, use `pd.concat` to combine all of my df objects, and then convert the pandas dataframe into a pyspakr dataframe. But this is very inefficient, is there another way to do this?

So far I have:

```
# list of file names
pickle_list = [f.name for f in dbutils.fs.ls(dbfs_path)]
df_list = list()
t0 = time.time()
# load dataframes and append to a list
for p in pickle_list:
  df_temp = pickle.load(open('/dbfs/monitoring_prickles/' + p, 'rb'))
  df_list.append(df_temp)
t1 = time.time() - t0

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

I define the schema following ([Converting Pandas dataframe into Spark dataframe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error)) and convert like so:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Auxiliar functions
def equivalent_type(f):
    if f == 'datetime64[ns]': return DateType()
    elif f == 'int64': return LongType()
    elif f == 'int32': return IntegerType()
    elif f == 'float64': return FloatType()
    else: return StringType()

def define_structure(string, format_type):
    try: typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
    except: typo = StringType()
    return StructField(string, typo)


# Given pandas dataframe, it will return a spark's dataframe.
def pandas_to_spark(pandas_df):
    columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
    types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
    struct_list = []
    for column, typo in zip(columns, types): 
      struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
    p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)

final_sdf = pandas_to_spark(final_df)
```

I am getting a warning though:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:776: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Expected a string or bytes object, got a 'int' object
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

Several questions: (1) is there a better way to do this since I am very new to Databricks/PySpark? (2) why does `display(final_sdf)` take more time than just running '`final_df`', and (3) what is Arrow optimization and the warning? Thanks!