# SparkError: PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict. DataBricks

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I converted a Pandas DataFrame into a Spark Dataframe using

```
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error
# Auxiliary functions
def equivalent_type(f):
    if f == 'datetime64[ns]': return TimestampType()
    elif f == 'int64': return LongType()
    elif f == 'int32': return IntegerType()
    elif f == 'float64': return FloatType()
    elif f == 'bool': return BooleanType()
    else: return StringType()

def define_structure(string, format_type):
    try: typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
    except: typo = StringType()
    return StructField(string, typo)

# Given pandas dataframe, it will return a spark's dataframe.
def pandas_to_spark(pandas_df):
    columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
    types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
    struct_list = []
    for column, typo in zip(columns, types): 
      struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
    p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)
```

```
sdf = pandas_to_spark(pdf)
```

I can view the dataframe `display(sdf)`

However, If I want to perform call a `collect()`  operation, or save the table: `sdf.write.saveAsTable("TESTsdf")`

I get the following error:

```
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)
```

Comment: why do you need to do it such complex way, why not `spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`? https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/convert-pandas-to-pyspark-dataframe/

Comment: Because of a similar error as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513355/converting-pandas-dataframe-into-spark-dataframe-error

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi yes. Turned out I had mixed dtypes in one of my columns, I belief due different types of Nulls/Nans/Nones. I see in my code the fix:  df[columns] = df[columns]                                                                   .where(pd.notnull(df[[columns]), None). I think this was the only thing I changed not sure

Comment: Yes this is the problem. I had an 'Int64' (different from 'int64') column in my df. This is a integer field that can also handle nulls. I threw out the line where I converted the fields to this datatype in pandas and I was able to save. Pyspark didn't like that I guess